# AT commands to activate CDMA modem?

Tags: dial-up, cellular-internet, cellular

Does anyone know the AT commands to activate a CDMA modem or update the roaming capabilities?

Comment: see http://www.canarysystems.com/nsupport/CDMA_AT_Commands.pdf

Comment: I've read that, and it doesn't help.